# How to connect Android app to SQL Server Directly in Eclipse (Monodroid apps are connecting)

Tags: android, sql-server, xamarin.android

I am searching in net about directly connect Android application to Sql Server develop using Eclipse. But not found solution. Most of them suggest use web service.

> But Android Application developing using Monodroid is connecting
>   directly to SQL Server.

How Monodroid achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Mono for Android ships with Mono.Data.Tds.dll and System.Data.dll which provide SQL Server support using TDS.

There may be Java libraries that would allow you to connect directly from an Android application written in Java, but I would recommend against that approach (I would also recommend against it even if you were using Mono for Android). As you mentioned seeing elsewhere, putting a service in between your app and the database is the right way to go. This would give you a much cleaner API to work against for the app, and would also be reusable elsewhere if you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C) can help

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=username;" + 
                                       "password=password;server=serverurl;" + 
                                       "Trusted_Connection=yes;" + 
                                       "database=database; " + 
                                       "connection timeout=30");
```

but I don't even know C# myself. I answered your question but later I found it was tagged monodroid

**EDIT**
Sorry, I didn't read the monodroid tag